# Popup Print Window in Vaadin 7 with Table

Tags: vaadin, popupwindow

I am new on Vaadin.
How to pass Table component to new popup screen in Vaadin 7? Assume I already created table using com.vaadin.ui.Table.

> Table aaa = new Table();

Currently Vaadin tutorial just show how to create print popup without pass component/data.
Based on below code

```
public static class PrintUI extends UI {
    @Override
        protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        // Have some content to print
        setContent(new Label(
            "<h1>Here's some dynamic content</h1>\n" +
            "<p>This is to be printed.</p>",
            ContentMode.HTML));

        // Print automatically when the window opens
        JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(
            "setTimeout(function() {" +
            "  print(); self.close();}, 0);");
    }
}
...

// Create an opener extension
BrowserWindowOpener opener =
        new BrowserWindowOpener(PrintUI.class);
opener.setFeatures("height=200,width=400,resizable");

// A button to open the printer-friendly page.
Button print = new Button("Click to Print");
opener.extend(print);
```

Appreciated if someone could show me how to pass Table aaa into PrintUI class.

Answer (score 4):

```
Window window = new Window("my test table popup");
window.setContent(table); 
window.setModal(true);
getUI().addWindow(window);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I have found to pass objects to the UI class in popup window is to store them in session:

```
    Table table = new Table();
    VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute("table", table);
```

In the popup window:

```
    Table t = (Table) VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("table");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also initialize your `Table` in your `PrintUI` class. If you need to initialize a specific `Table` instance, you can pass, let's say, your table id parameter to the UI via `.getParameter("idTable")` (which, in the end, works as adding a `GET` parameter to the URL) and then retrieve it in your `PrintUI`'s `init()` method via the request parameter with `.getParameter("idTable")`.